# matplotlib and Pillow (PIL) incompatible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have the following program that does not work if I run:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

##MATPLOTLIB STUFF --------------------------------------------
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.randn(10)

ax.plot(x,y)
fig.savefig('image1.png', bboxtoinches = 'tight')


##PIL STUFF --------------------------------------------------
root = tk.Tk()

graph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image1.png")
w1 = tk.Label(root, image=graph).pack(side='right')

explanation = "A matplotlib plot"
w2 = tk.Label(root, justify=tk.LEFT, padx=10, 
text=explanation).pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

but DOES work if I delete the matplotlib stuff and run

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

##PIL STUFF --------------------------------------------------
root = tk.Tk()

graph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image1.png")
w1 = tk.Label(root, image=graph).pack(side='right')

explanation = "A matplotlib plot"
w2 = tk.Label(root, justify=tk.LEFT, padx=10, 
text=explanation).pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

As a matter of fact, the line that seems to cause the problem is

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
```

If I do include this line then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proj_1_images.py", line 20, in <module>
    w1 = tk.Label(root, image=graph).pack(side='right')
  File "C:\Users\Luke Polson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2760, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Luke Polson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage10" doesn't exist
```

Why would matplotlib be causing this error?

Answer (score -1):

The code runs smoothly for me, your problem is that pyimage10 is stored in memory, but cant find the path, restarting kernel and clearing all declared variables in memory will fix this problem.

Comment: Why the weird formatting? And why do you assume that OP is using Jupyter or something similar (i.e he can restart kernel/clear all declared variables)

Comment: You dont need jupyter to restart kernel, I have had the same problem countless times working with a big project in tkinter. The formatting here is purely because of the contrast and easier readability, the reason for the formatting in OP's post was because it was hard to read the error message, and when i didnt put it in the `code` tags it wouldnt allow me to post because i had code outside those tags unfortunately. @FlyingTeller

Comment: What is your understanding of what "kernel" is in this context?

Comment: compiler @FlyingTeller as it is the name of the compiler within spyder